# How to assign a content type to a specific block in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-type, drupal-panels, drupal-blocks

I want some content types to open in a block in the sidebar, not in the main content area, ideally without refreshing the main content area.

How can this be done in Drupal 7? I was thinking of using Panels but have not found the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the view on the left contains multiple node items. What must be edited in the left view by a user? And the column right shows all the information of the chosen node?

Comment: The body text can be edited in the left view. The right column should display the full node.

Comment: Maybe an iframe would be an easier solution?

Comment: That's an option, you can use an jQuery call to load the requested node and put this information in the div in the right column.

Answer (score 1):

you can add blocks to the specific content types and place these blocks in an region (such as sidebar). In the template you can add this region. And what do you mean with "without refreshing", do you want the content to be updated client side?

Comment: I have a two column layout. A view on the left. I would like that when I click on a node listed in the view, it is opened in the right column, without refreshing the full page.     By not refreshing, I mean that the fields in the view on the left are editable, so I don't want the user to lose what he just typed if he clicks on a link.